# Symfony2: Transformation of database records for displaying

Tags: php, symfony, formatting

I have rather theoretical question about proper approach of using Symfony though I believe the approach is to be same for any other PHP framework.

I have tariff objects stored in database. I want to provide a cost model for each tariff basing on user input.

My initial approach was to create an array, one's each element would contain data from corresponding tariff object and calculated data. All of that was done in controller's action method.

Later I have created another class CostModel and then created an array CostModel[], which than was passed to $this->render() method. Again it's done in controller.

This approach works well enough. However, since I have not much experience with Symfony, I have doubts that this approach - performing calculations in controller - is good one.

Is there any better way for this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question could have more than one answer as it is very opinion-based.

What I can say without any doubt about controller's code is that the less it is the more is good. Why I said that? Because controller code isn't reusable, because controllers are made to "connected" views and business logic (keep attention: connect, not encapsulate) and a general rule that I follow when I develop with Symfony2, is to write, into controller, lines of code for "objects" that are directly accessible from controller (form, request, views, and so on); all code that isn't related to these concepts should be migrated elsewhere.

Your solution is a good starting point but we cannot judge as we haven't more details and we don't know the architecture of your software. What can I say - and I hope you already know - is that you can pass to render (so to view templating system; I suppose you are using twig) directly the ArrayCollection you've obtained querying the database (so basically you don't neeed CostModel[] array). So, maybe, your approach is good but not the best: maybe you can take advantage of Repository facility, write a good query that can extract and calculate data for you (in a more optimized way) and use repository directly into controller. That way you could at the same time, migrate code where it should stay, write less number of code lines, do some optimitazion (or better, let Doctrine do for you) and you don't need to create a brand new class (model).